# Hyper-V: after external switch setup - host lose internet in browser (but I still connected to it)

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v

I have a dedicated server with Windows 10 - far away from me, in datacenter.

I create external switch in Hyper-V to connect my VMs to Internet with "white" IPs. I attach it to NIC with internet (server also have other NIC, but it not connected, maybe for datacenter local network, I think).

When I apply this external switch, my host lost internet in browser (!), but I still have connection by RDP without any problem (!). Somehow I see my server in Internet, but my server not see Internet.

---

On previous server I have connection with external switch without any problems. What can be cause of problem? Maybe it something with new 'Default Switch' in Hyper-V, that cannot be deleted?

Comment: Win10 isn't ideal as a server, but what you're seeing is expected.  When you configure an external virtual switch, the networking information (TCP/IP info) is moved off the physical NIC and onto the new virtual switch.  The default virtual switch is a non-configurable NAT implementation, there's no reason to use it, if you're using an external switch.   Do you have MAC restrictions, as you're new virtual switch will have a different MAC than the physical NIC.  Have you verified that all the TCP info is correct, maybe the gateway is missing?

Comment: @essjae thank you for your attention! Hyper-V somehow erase DNS-server entries from main connection when it creates external switch (and bring it back when I remove switch).

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution:

When Hyper-V creates an external switch, it removes the DNS-servers from main connection settings. After switch delete - it restores it back.

So I wrote it manually to main connection - and everything works fine.